# Responsively stack three divs on the right that are not all on the right to begin with

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm using display:grid along with display:flex to create a layout like the one called 'Normal' in the image below. I also have some javascript that lets me collapse the blue and light blue divs. I'm having a very difficult time crafting a media query that will let me put all the divs on the right like in the image. The red div expands to the size of its contents while the blue divs get overflow:scroll.
[image: Two-column to one-column responsive layout]
This image simplifies the actual situation a bit; I actually also have stuff in the middle of the page too.
Here's a pared down version of my html (I know the grid is a little different than the one in the image above):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Width Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ResponsiveWidth.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="one"><p>One</p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille pork belly shankle bacon landjaeger, cupim flank meatball t-bone capicola leberkas. Tenderloin short loin venison ribeye drumstick, corned beef pork belly pork chop jerky kielbasa salami cupim. Drumstick ham hock filet mignon rump doner. Ham tri-tip venison hamburger rump, jowl ball tip bresaola tenderloin jerky. Chicken cow salami, chuck pancetta tail swine pork loin pork chop turkey beef ribs capicola boudin.

        Meatball flank t-bone pancetta spare ribs landjaeger boudin pork chop leberkas jerky alcatra meatloaf swine ball tip. Pork chop meatball beef ribs ribeye t-bone. Tongue pig flank shoulder alcatra doner ground round kielbasa jerky bresaola beef swine. Tenderloin swine ribeye andouille tongue drumstick fatback.

        Ball tip shankle brisket shoulder salami bresaola leberkas alcatra venison short ribs meatloaf ground round pastrami t-bone flank. Chuck bacon bresaola alcatra t-bone ribeye shank drumstick pork filet mignon ham hock burgdoggen chicken doner. Tenderloin shoulder spare ribs, burgdoggen hamburger sirloin cupim pork loin turkey short loin tail jowl ham hock. Sausage jerky alcatra, ground round cupim chicken short loin turducken bresaola porchetta beef ribs capicola pastrami meatloaf. Rump bacon doner buffalo short loin picanha drumstick cupim.
      </div>
      <div class="two"><p>Two</p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille pork belly shankle bacon landjaeger, cupim flank meatball t-bone capicola leberkas. Tenderloin short loin venison ribeye drumstick, corned beef pork belly pork chop jerky kielbasa salami cupim. Drumstick ham hock filet mignon rump doner. Ham tri-tip venison hamburger rump, jowl ball tip bresaola tenderloin jerky. Chicken cow salami, chuck pancetta tail swine pork loin pork chop turkey beef ribs capicola boudin.

        Meatball flank t-bone pancetta spare ribs landjaeger boudin pork chop leberkas jerky alcatra meatloaf swine ball tip. Pork chop meatball beef ribs ribeye t-bone. Tongue pig flank shoulder alcatra doner ground round kielbasa jerky bresaola beef swine. Tenderloin swine ribeye andouille tongue drumstick fatback.

        Ball tip shankle brisket shoulder salami bresaola leberkas alcatra venison short ribs meatloaf ground round pastrami t-bone flank. Chuck bacon bresaola alcatra t-bone ribeye shank drumstick pork filet mignon ham hock burgdoggen chicken doner. Tenderloin shoulder spare ribs, burgdoggen hamburger sirloin cupim pork loin turkey short loin tail jowl ham hock. Sausage jerky alcatra, ground round cupim chicken short loin turducken bresaola porchetta beef ribs capicola pastrami meatloaf. Rump bacon doner buffalo short loin picanha drumstick cupim.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="three"><p>Three<p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille pork belly shankle bacon landjaeger, cupim flank meatball t-bone capicola leberkas. Tenderloin short loin venison ribeye drumstick, corned beef pork belly pork chop jerky kielbasa salami cupim. Drumstick ham hock filet mignon rump doner. Ham tri-tip venison hamburger rump, jowl ball tip bresaola tenderloin jerky. Chicken cow salami, chuck pancetta tail swine pork loin pork chop turkey beef ribs capicola boudin.

        Meatball flank t-bone pancetta spare ribs landjaeger boudin pork chop leberkas jerky alcatra meatloaf swine ball tip. Pork chop meatball beef ribs ribeye t-bone. Tongue pig flank shoulder alcatra doner ground round kielbasa jerky bresaola beef swine. Tenderloin swine ribeye andouille tongue drumstick fatback.

        Ball tip shankle brisket shoulder salami bresaola leberkas alcatra venison short ribs meatloaf ground round pastrami t-bone flank. Chuck bacon bresaola alcatra t-bone ribeye shank drumstick pork filet mignon ham hock burgdoggen chicken doner. Tenderloin shoulder spare ribs, burgdoggen hamburger sirloin cupim pork loin turkey short loin tail jowl ham hock. Sausage jerky alcatra, ground round cupim chicken short loin turducken bresaola porchetta beef ribs capicola pastrami meatloaf. Rump bacon doner buffalo short loin picanha drumstick cupim.
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css:

```
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 300px);
  grid-template-rows: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.left, .right {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 3/4;

}

.one, .two, .three {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .left {
    grid-column: 3/4;
  }
}
```

I've tried putting the divs in the same place using grid-column but they just overlap each other instead of sharing the space. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you read this article to give you a strong foundation on css grids:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

As for your question:

First of all, let's indent your code and add some

tags to those floating blocks of text to make everything a little bit more readable :)

Having done that, to change the positioning of your elements inside your grid, use

- grid-column-start
- grid-column-end
- grid-row-start
- grid-row-end

In your code, you have a 3x3 grid, so if you want to adhere yourself to that, I've prepared some sample code for you. If you want to adhere entirely to the image examples, you will need to flesh out your grid in more detail.

For now, if you fix your css, using your 3x3 grid, the media query should kick in and you should have this:

[image]

The css + html is this:

```css
body {
min-height: 100%;
display: grid;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 300px);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 200px);
overflow: hidden;
}


.left, .right {
grid-row: 1/4;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-direction: column;
}

.left {
//grid-column: 1/2;
}

.right {
grid-column: 3/4;

}

.one, .two, .three {
padding: 20px;
overflow: scroll;
}

.one {
background-color: red;
}

.two {
background-color: blue;
}

.three {
background-color: #00ffff;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    
    .left {
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: span 2;
        order: 1;
    }
    .left .one {
        grid-row-start:1;
        grid-row-end:1;
    }
    .left .two {
        grid-row-start:1;
        grid-row-end:2;
    }
    .right {
        grid-column-start:3;
        grid-row-start:3;
        grid-row-end:3;
        order:2;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Width Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ResponsiveWidth.css">
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="one">
            <p>One</p>
            <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille pork belly shankle bacon landjaeger, cupim flank meatball t-bone capicola leberkas. Tenderloin short loin venison ribeye drumstick, corned beef pork belly pork chop jerky kielbasa salami cupim. Drumstick ham hock filet mignon rump doner. Ham tri-tip venison hamburger rump, jowl ball tip bresaola tenderloin jerky. Chicken cow salami, chuck pancetta tail swine pork loin pork chop turkey beef ribs capicola boudin.</p>

            <p>Meatball flank t-bone pancetta spare ribs landjaeger boudin pork chop leberkas jerky alcatra meatloaf swine ball tip. Pork chop meatball beef ribs ribeye t-bone. Tongue pig flank shoulder alcatra doner ground round kielbasa jerky bresaola beef swine. Tenderloin swine ribeye andouille tongue drumstick fatback.</p>

            <p>Ball tip shankle brisket shoulder salami bresaola leberkas alcatra venison short ribs meatloaf ground round pastrami t-bone flank. Chuck bacon bresaola alcatra t-bone ribeye shank drumstick pork filet mignon ham hock burgdoggen chicken doner. Tenderloin shoulder spare ribs, burgdoggen hamburger sirloin cupim pork loin turkey short loin tail jowl ham hock. Sausage jerky alcatra, ground round cupim chicken short loin turducken bresaola porchetta beef ribs capicola pastrami meatloaf. Rump bacon doner buffalo short loin picanha drumstick cupim.</p>
</div>
        <div class="two"><p>Two</p>
            <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille pork belly shankle bacon landjaeger, cupim flank meatball t-bone capicola leberkas. Tenderloin short loin venison ribeye drumstick, corned beef pork belly pork chop jerky kielbasa salami cupim. Drumstick ham hock filet mignon rump doner. Ham tri-tip venison hamburger rump, jowl ball tip bresaola tenderloin jerky. Chicken cow salami, chuck pancetta tail swine pork loin pork chop turkey beef ribs capicola boudin.</p>

            <p>Meatball flank t-bone pancetta spare ribs landjaeger boudin pork chop leberkas jerky alcatra meatloaf swine ball tip. Pork chop meatball beef ribs ribeye t-bone. Tongue pig flank shoulder alcatra doner ground round kielbasa jerky bresaola beef swine. Tenderloin swine ribeye andouille tongue drumstick fatback.</p>

            <p>Ball tip shankle brisket shoulder salami bresaola leberkas alcatra venison short ribs meatloaf ground round pastrami t-bone flank. Chuck bacon bresaola alcatra t-bone ribeye shank drumstick pork filet mignon ham hock burgdoggen chicken doner. Tenderloin shoulder spare ribs, burgdoggen hamburger sirloin cupim pork loin turkey short loin tail jowl ham hock. Sausage jerky alcatra, ground round cupim chicken short loin turducken bresaola porchetta beef ribs capicola pastrami meatloaf. Rump bacon doner buffalo short loin picanha drumstick cupim.</p>
</div>
        </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="three"><p>Three<p>
            <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille pork belly shankle bacon landjaeger, cupim flank meatball t-bone capicola leberkas. Tenderloin short loin venison ribeye drumstick, corned beef pork belly pork chop jerky kielbasa salami cupim. Drumstick ham hock filet mignon rump doner. Ham tri-tip venison hamburger rump, jowl ball tip bresaola tenderloin jerky. Chicken cow salami, chuck pancetta tail swine pork loin pork chop turkey beef ribs capicola boudin.</p>

            <p>Meatball flank t-bone pancetta spare ribs landjaeger boudin pork chop leberkas jerky alcatra meatloaf swine ball tip. Pork chop meatball beef ribs ribeye t-bone. Tongue pig flank shoulder alcatra doner ground round kielbasa jerky bresaola beef swine. Tenderloin swine ribeye andouille tongue drumstick fatback.</p>

            <p>Ball tip shankle brisket shoulder salami bresaola leberkas alcatra venison short ribs meatloaf ground round pastrami t-bone flank. Chuck bacon bresaola alcatra t-bone ribeye shank drumstick pork filet mignon ham hock burgdoggen chicken doner. Tenderloin shoulder spare ribs, burgdoggen hamburger sirloin cupim pork loin turkey short loin tail jowl ham hock. Sausage jerky alcatra, ground round cupim chicken short loin turducken bresaola porchetta beef ribs capicola pastrami meatloaf. Rump bacon doner buffalo short loin picanha drumstick cupim.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

If you look closely, you will notice I commented out grid-column since you are incorrectly utilising it.

I hope this helps
G

Comment: Thanks @Sotkra, the article definitely helped me understand some things. The main thing I'm struggling to understand is: if I want the red div to always expand depending on it's content, the dark blue div to take up only a fixed amount of the remaining space in the narrow view, and then the light blue take up the rest, how do I do it? It seems like I want the right side items in the narrow view to be in a display: flex grid together, but on the normal view I want them on opposite sides of each other. I am trying to follow the idea illustrated in the image.

Comment: A big fat fair warning: https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS+Grid+Layout
Firefox 52 ESR has overflow issues and anyone saying WTH support 52 doesn't understand Mozilla's anti-user policies. Additionally Microsoft, who initially proposed the spec sat on their butts for years without updating up to IE15. I highly recommend using flexbox, it's much more mature and supported by *all* browsers that developers *should* be supporting.

Comment: Peter: you can switch display mode's depending on your media queries, if need be, alternating between display:flex and display:grid, for example. If you want the red to always expand, give it a height of auto, give blue a fixed height, however much you desire, then give light blue the rest. Your definition of rows would thus be: auto, #px, auto, for example

Comment: Almost forgot: you can use flex properties in conjunction with grid items, specifically justify-content and align-items.